# How to make a Container, Which is Divided into Two Equal Parts. So Now I want to make Left Div Sticky and Right Div to Scroll Vertically,

Tags: html, css, scroll

How can I make a container which is divided into two equal parts such that the left side is sticky and the right side scrolls vertically?

Please Have a Look at this Question: https://gevma-template.webflow.io/menu

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you or I can modify if you wanted a different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you wanted something like this.

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="A">      // STICKY DIV
        <span>A</span>
    </div>

    <div class="B">      // SCROLLING DIV
         <span>B</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  height: 500vh;
  width:100vw;

  .A {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .B {
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    left: 10%;
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }

}
```

This is the working example

https://jsfiddle.net/gokv3pht/

Comment: I tried your code, but the issue with your code is Container A remains Fixed Even If I have the infinite scroll on Container B. I Want something exactly like this: https://gevma-template.webflow.io/menu